# Command from Jmeter master

Tags: jmeter

How can I find a Slave IP address to pass in case of starting Jmeter Master. As Jmeter slave has been successfully launched and waiting for a command from Master. 
Anyone expertise in Jmeter help, please!

Answer (score 0):

When you launch [jmeter-server script](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/bin/jmeter-server.bat) it prints some diagnostic information to the stdout and this information includes the IP address the slave binds to, look for `endpoint` word:

[image]

See [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) article, it should help you to better understand JMeter's client-server execution mode

And of course you can determine the IP address by means of the underlying operating system i.e. using [ipconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ipconfig) command for Windows or [ifconfig](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ifconfig) for Linux/Unix/MacOS